# How to check Json File if the keys are valid and create a array of objects in c++ with RapidJson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am trying to to create a class/struct array out of a json file with rapidjson. The file contains the following content:

```
{
  "item" : [
{"name": "chair",
 "attribute": "iron",
 "available": "false"},

{"Name": "bed",
 "attribute": "wood",
 "available": "true",
 "attribute":"soft"},

{"naeM": "lamp",
 "attribute": "iron",
 "available": "false",
 "Number": "4"},

....

{"name": "mirrow",
 "attribute": "iron",
 "available": "false"}
           ],

"category" : [
{"name": "kitchen"}, {"name": "living room"},{"name": "bedroom"} ]
}
```

I had looked up all the info I could get on rapidjson.org and the examples but don't really get how to check for a specific key in each array object of validation if the key exist(case sensitive) and no duplicates in the object.

For example, here I want to check if each array object has the key  "name" in it or if only the keys "name", "attribute" and "available" are present. The closed to get there would probably be to create a json schema valid check but I don't really get the syntax of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple program that checks the whether each `item` has those three attributes:

```
#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING 1
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace std;

bool check_or_error(bool check, string message) {
    if (!check) {
        cerr << message << endl;
    }
    return check;
}

int main() {
    Document doc;
    {
        // This just loads JSON from a file into `doc`.
        ifstream fs("test2.json");
        IStreamWrapper isw(fs);
        doc.ParseStream(isw);
        if (doc.HasParseError()) {
            cerr << "Parse error " << doc.GetParseError() << " at " << doc.GetErrorOffset();
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Grab the element under `item` and coerce it to an array.
    const Value::Array& a = doc["item"].GetArray();
    // This is a standard iterator pattern; we set `it` equal to every element
    // in turn. We use `cbegin`/`cend` to get const iterators, which do not
    // modify the array.
    for (auto it = cbegin(a); it != cend(a); it++) {
        bool ok = true;
        // Is it an object? if not, complain and move to the next element.
        ok = check_or_error(it->IsObject(), "Item is not an object");
        if (!ok) continue;

        const Value::Object& item = it->GetObject();
        int idx = std::distance(cbegin(a), it);
        static std::string mandatory[] = { "name", "attribute", "available" };
        // For every mandatory key ...
        for (const auto& key : mandatory) {
            // ... check if it is present or complain
            // The weird `(stringstream() << ...).str()` construct
            // allows us to creata formatted message as a string.
            ok = check_or_error(item.HasMember(key), (stringstream() << "item[" << idx << "] missing key " << key).str());
            if (!ok) continue;

            // ... check if it is a string or complain
            const Value& v = item[key];
            check_or_error(v.IsString(), (stringstream() << "item[" << idx << "][" << key << " not a string ").str());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it does not check for duplicate keys, as RapidJSON hides that for you.

The corresponding JSONSchema would be: ([test for yourself](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/))

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "item",
    "category"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "item": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "name",
          "attribute",
          "available"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "attribute": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "available": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "category": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: first of all- thanks for the effort.
im so sorry, i dont quit get the code - i am a total noob. could you explain it a bit?

Comment: I added some comments. If you tell me which bits are unclear I can give you pointers.

Comment: I think I am missing something: you load the test2.json file but where do you load the schema.json file to valid check it? Because the next step you allready creating an array of item. And while you create the array you check if it is a object.

Comment: There you check if the keys exist, which means you don't use the schema? But by checking only for the existing keys some other errors could occur when there are for example more attributes/parameters except for the keys which should also response with an error because the file is not valid because it does not fit the requered schema that validate that the file is correct and safe to load. what about the other object "category" is it just recall the same function? Then I would have 2 array stack instead of one?

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you wanted to test jsonschema from C++. I suggest a JSONSchema library, then.